# Crash in PyObject_Hash

Tags: python, ctypes, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I am hitting a periodic crash when calling `PyObject_Hash`. Below is the traceback:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  PyObject_Hash (v=0x0) at Objects/object.c:1107
#1  0x00002ac08c50c8e8 in tuplehash (v=<value optimized out>) at Objects/tupleobject.c:351
#2  0x00002ac08c50c8e8 in tuplehash (v=<value optimized out>) at Objects/tupleobject.c:351
#3  0x00002ac08c50c8e8 in tuplehash (v=<value optimized out>) at Objects/tupleobject.c:351
#4  0x00002ac08c50c8e8 in tuplehash (v=<value optimized out>) at Objects/tupleobject.c:351
#5  0x00002ac08c4f352f in PyDict_GetItem (op=0x2ac08fb9ed70, key=0x2ac08f839750) at Objects/dictobject.c:719
#6  0x00002ac08c558781 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=0x2ac096fbcda8, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2373
#7  0x00002ac08c55e459 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x2ac08fb8b7b0, globals=<value optimized out>, locals=<value optimized out>, args=0x2ac0933893d8, argcount=3, kws=0x0, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, 
    defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3582
#8  0x00002ac08c4df9e2 in function_call (func=0x2ac09775f848, arg=0x2ac0933893c0, kw=0x0) at Objects/funcobject.c:526
#9  0x00002ac08c4b1868 in PyObject_Call (func=0x2ac09775f848, arg=0x2ac0933893c0, kw=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2546
#10 0x00002ac08c4b4b75 in call_function_tail (callable=0x2ac09775f848, format=<value optimized out>) at Objects/abstract.c:2578
#11 PyObject_CallFunction (callable=0x2ac09775f848, format=<value optimized out>) at Objects/abstract.c:2602
```

This crash happens about once in every 8-10 calls. I see that `v` is not valid, but I am not sure why this happens only periodically, and I cannot determine the root cause of the problem.

Comment: How is this question related to ctypes?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without the code that calls it.